# Assembler 16 BIT DOS keyboard input output on screen error

Tags: assembly, buffer, dosbox, 16-bit

I have following code
Basically Im trying output string on middle of console window, string is inputed from keyboard

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 200h
.DATA
Buffer DB 81, ? , 81 dup (?)
.CODE
Start: mov AH,0Ah
mov DX, offset Buffer
int 21h
mov AH, 0Fh
int 10h
mov AH,0
int 10h
mov AX,80
sub AL, Buffer[1]
mov BL,2 
div BL
mov BH,0
mov DH,12
mov DL,AL
mov AH,2
int 10h
mov BL, Buffer[1]
mov BH,0
mov Buffer[BX+2],'$'
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah, 0
 int 16h
 mov ah, 4Ch
 int 21h
END Start
```

and my output in DosBox is very strange
[image: The is output]

can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have to set `dx` to the address of `Buffer` plus 2, before calling interrupt 21h service 09h.

Comment: Thanks man it is working

Comment: Not a man, but you're welcome.